# It is possible to automatically discover the services hosted on the ESB by the GREG

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-governance-registry

I’m working with the WSAS, GREG and the ESB of wso2, I have seen a lot of examples of discovering services hosted on the WSAS with the GREG and using the ESB as a client of the GREG, but as a government strategy, I think I should have registered and managed all my services, them it would be useful if I could automatically discover the services hosted in the ESB to, so, I try to do it in the same way as with the WSAS but it didn´t work.
It is possible to automatically discover the services hosted on the ESB by the GREG?

Answer (score 0):

it should work for ESB also
Did you configure ESB DiscoveryProxy at ESB axis2.xml?

[1]https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/WS-Discovery+with+Governance+Registry
[2]http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/08/rediscover-soa-wso2-carbon-wsdiscovery/

Comment: Hello Ratha and thanks for your answer, when I include the same parameter that works for the WSAS in the ESB : <parameter name="DiscoveryProxy">https://greg_host:port/services/DiscoveryProxy</parameter> the GREG don’t discover the services and the ESB console show me this: [-] [HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1] ERROR SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Comment: I already did that and it doesn't work, the truestores of ESB and GRGE are the same, nevertheless I added the .crt of the ESB on the GREG and the one of the GREG on the ESB, when I was doing it, the console told me that the cert was already in the truestore, but I added any way. Please tell me if I’m missing something. Thanks Ratha

Comment: any thoughts about this?